# Excel VBA Convert Formula to Value In Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba

I need vba code in Excel to convert formula to its value, but only in specific column and only convert till last row with data

Example: Sheet 1 Column B, E:J filled with lookup formula to get data from Sheet 2. Formula is filled from row 1 to 1500. Based on table array in sheet 2. Sheet 1 row 1 to 1000 return lookup result. I need to convert column B, E:J row 1 to 1000 formula to value while row 1001 to 1500 is still have lookup formula

From internet search i can use this code...

```
Sub FormulaToValue()
Dim N As Long, rng As Range

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(N, Columns.Count))

rng.Value2 = rng.Value2
End Sub
```

This code will convert formula to value until last row with data only, in this case only row 1 to 1000 will be converted. But this code convert all columns in the sheet. I think i need to change Columns.Count to specific column range but i don't now how to write the right code. I'm not familiar with vba code

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Convert formula in range defined as rng to its value

Answer (score 3):

Put the column you require in this line

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(N, Columns.Count))
```

e.g. 
If you want to use column E

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(N, 5))
```

If you want to use multiple columns you can use a loop to go through them

```
Sub FormulaToValue()

    Dim N As Long, rng As Range

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("B", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")

    ' Read through each column
    Dim col As Variant
    For Each col In arr
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(N, col))
        rng.Value2 = rng.Value2
    Next col

End Sub
```

If you have columns like B:E then you need to go through them individually to find the last cell with data in each.

Comment: Ok, that works. Only formula in column E converted to its value. But how to convert formula in multiple columns instead just one column? Let say the columns is B, E to J

Comment: wow, I'm a regular visitor of your blog. They're really great and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

I have this RON code where i have tweaked my excel where in excel file path there is formula and while i am trying to send an email VBA is picking reading it as formula and giving error no cells were found in line

For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

thankful if you can please advice

code copied here

Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

```
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the K:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("K1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "XXXXXX"
            .Body = "XXXXX"
            'rng = rng.Text
            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send  'Or use .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub